# What will be the regular expression for following date and time format like YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS.?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, regex

I want to validate the textbox as per date & time format like `YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS` so I required regular expression for date & Time using the javascript.

Please let me know the answer as soon as possible.

Required RE for `YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS date Time format`.

Comment: You would be foolish to use regex for that.

Comment: Javascript or Java ? Hotdog or dog?

Comment: @kayaman so what should i use for.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dear, Here is your answer** :

```
var r = /^((((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](0[13578]|1[02])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](0[13456789]|1[012])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-](0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-](29)\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])))$/g;

r.test('2014-06-24 15:49:05'); // true
r.test('2016-02-29 23:19:20'); // true [leap year]
r.test('2015/02/29 23:19:20'); // false
r.test('2010.11.31 10:00:02'); // false
r.test('1956.10.12 24:10:02'); // false
```

**Thanks & Cheers**

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, your answer is not fully useful but at least it lead me on right way. Finally I got my solution from your answer. Thanks for your answer I really appreciate for you.